# Transforming Connection String in Web.Release.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, web.config-transform

I am trying to use the Web.Release.config file to store an alternative MySQL connection string ready for the live environment, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

In my Web.config I have my local db set up like so:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=local;Uid=userid;Pwd=12345678;" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then my Web.Release.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=live;Uid=userid;Pwd=12345678;" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And I am grabbing my connection string in code using:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

I have tried switching the config version and running and I get the exact same data being pulled out, all from the local db. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Yuck, don't check your connection string into source control! Instead, use your transforms to insert tokens into your config. Then have your automated release process replace those tokens with the actual configuration appropriate for the environment being released to. Or switch it to read from environment variables within the environment.

Comment: @mason got any guidance on how to do either of the things you just suggested?

Comment: Environment variables are easy. You can retrieve them with a [simple method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2). Describing how to insert tokenized values in your configuration file is more complex, and dependent on how you do your deployments. How do you deploy to an environment? Right click, Publish? PowerShell scripts? TFS? Azure DevOps? Octopus?

Comment: @mason I'll be deploying via publish

Comment: And where are you deploying to? IIS hosted on your company's server? Some 3rd party hosted server? Azure? AWS?

Comment: @mason iis on our own server